# How to calculate rest-frame luminosity in a specific wavelength band?

Tags: observational-astronomy, luminosity, spectrometry, flux

For instance, I have a set of templates whose y is in Jy and x is in Angstroms. I have both of their rest-frame and obs-frame wavelength (i.e.  redshift). I want to know their luminosity in one specific waveband like rest-frame UKIRT.H (i.e.,~1.6um, L<sub>1.6</sub>) or IRAC2 (i.e.,~4.5um, L<sub>4.5</sub>).

I'm confused about how to calculate the rest-frame luminosity. For now, I convolve the rest wavelength and response curve so get an average flux density and times effective wavelength of the filter to get flux. And using redshift to get luminosity.

Am I right? I'm a little concern that maybe I should convolve obs wavelength and response curve?

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem. See the [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/878398).